# Is there a way to convert a Object into a boolean in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, boolean

Recently, I stumped the `__bool__` fuction in Python that converts a class into a bool and that is called when performing a condition. Doing

```
if expression:
    pass
```

is actually doing this internally

```
if bool(expression):
    pass
```

thus, it is possible to return different True/False depending on the value of the expression.

Is there an equivalent function in Ruby to the `__bool__` in Python that does that same thing? (I looked at `!`, `!~` and `===` without any success.)

Answer (score 3):

No. Ruby is much stricter about these things than most languages: only `false` and `nil` are falsy, by language design. There is no way to override this.

Where you'd ask `if items:` in Python, you ask `if items.empty?`; where you'd ask Python `if determinant:`, Ruby idiom is `unless determinant.zero?`. Zen of Python is "Explicit is better than implicit"? Hah. :D

Comment: So it wouldn't be possible to override some method in the Fixnum class so that doing `if 0` returns false?

Comment: That is correct. `0` is neither `false` nor `nil`, so it is truthy; this reduces the amount of surprises and inadvertent mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `!!` trick to turn something into its explicit boolean value in ruby, but as Amadan said, it's not particularly relevant. The way that `!!` works is that if an object, `o`, is truthy then `!o` will return `false` and if `o` is falsey, then `!o` will return true. Putting a second `!`, so you have `!!o` will return the negation of the negation, which is equivalent to the boolean value of the object.